# Angular8+ ngswitch nested component doesn't update the view

Tags: angular, ngzone

I have the strange issue with component view rendering.
Part of the component i work on looks like this:

```html
<div [ngSwitch]="step">
  <comp1 *ngSwitchCase="'step1'"></comp1>

  <comp2 *ngSwitchCase="'step2'"></comp2>
</div>
```

Comp2 uses some shared component like this:

```html
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let p of products">
    {{p}}
    <change-quantity [quantity]="p.quantity" 
                     (quantityChanged)="onChangeQuantity(p,$event)">
    </change-quantity>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The problem i have is that `<change-quantity>` doesn't render the model changes if i init parent component with `step = 'step2'`, but if i start from `step='step1'` and then go to `step='step2'` it works well.
Changing quantity looks like this:

```js
onChangeQuantity(product, ev) {
  product.quantity = ev;
}
```

I have found a workaround to use `ngZone` when changing product quantity model, but i think this is not the right way to do this. I'll be happy to find better way than triggering `ngZone` manually.

UPD: I tried to

1. replace `*ngSwitch` with few `*ngIf`s - no success
2. tried to force change detection by recreating array like this(no success either):

```js
  onChangeQuantity(product, ev) {
    let result = [];
    this.products.forEach((prod) => {
      if(prod.id === product.id) {
        prod.quantity = ev;
      }
      let p = JSON.parse(
        JSON.stringify({
          id: prod.id,
          default_addon: prod.default_addon,
          quantity: prod.id === product.id ? ev : prod.quantity
        })
      );
      result.push(p);
    });
    this.products = result;
  }
```

Comment: Sorry, I can not provide the solution for your case. I hope from the point we stand on you can finish it.

Comment: how do use the ngZone when it helps? probably the problem somewhere in between the components interaction

Answer (score 0):

I bet `products` array is updated without updating the reference. 
[Here it is](https://chrislo.ca/angular-2345-change-detection-on-data-bound-array-pushunshift-popshift-or-splice/) explained with possible solutions.

Comment: i don't understand why it happens depending on ngSwitch value.

Comment: even when i switch to ngIf instead of ngSwitch it works the same

Comment: changing the value used in the condition leads to rendering. and changing the array without changing the reference does not trigger rendering

Comment: i have tried to recreate the array and objects but this didn't help, see UPD section in question descrtiption :)

Comment: well, my bet failed (: looking into the current code I don't see a possible reason. is it possible to do a stackblitz with reproduction?